# Polygons are unable to be edited and have no feature, although they are listed in attribute table with three features

Tags: qgis, shapefile, polygon

I found that several lakes in the [GRanD database (global reservoirs and dams)](http://sedac.ciesin.columbia.edu/downloads/data/grand-v1/grand-v1-reservoirs-rev01/reservoirs-rev01-global-shp.zip) are unable to be selected for editing like normal polygons, and they have no feature at all, although they are shown in the attribute table with three features: GRanD ID, area and Poly_SRC.

May I ask:

1. Why are these polygons corrupted?
2. How to fix them to be normal polygons that can be edited?

Image 1: one lake polygon with no feature shown:
[image]

Image 2: the lakes shown in the attribute table with three features:
[image]

Image 3: The GRanD ID of each lake cannot be shown as label for each of these 25 mysterious polygons:
[image]

The shapefile is shared in this [link](https://sites.google.com/site/oatcracker2013/home/files/missing_lakes.zip?attredirects=0&d=1).

Comment: Where is the data sitting? Is it still in a database? Can you export the data out to a local file and try edit that? Could it be that there is a read-only lock on the location the data is sitting?

Comment: Hi Keagan, I can edit other polygons on this vector layer of lakes, and also I can export the attributes of this layer as CSV file. So, I'm not sure if it is because the shape file is locked as read-only. Can you advise if there is such as setting for shape file, and how to unlock it in QGIS? Thank you.

Comment: In ArcMap I would try running the "Repair Geometry" Tool. I am not 100% familiar with QGIS, but perhaps running the v.clean tool might help. I did a quick search and found this: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/167421/repairing-geometry-using-qgis

Comment: I tried the Geometry validator plugin, and the error message for each of these 25 polygons is "ring 0 not closed"... seems the geometry of the polygons is problematic...

Comment: I tried the suggestion from the link below to fix the "ring x not closed" error. However, the polygon regenerated from the boundary line of the lake is still ghost shape..... Post : https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/170942/fixing-polygons-with-ring-not-closed-errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like something wrong in the shapefile, it might be read only and cannot be edited. I changed the format of the vector file from shapefile to MapInfo Tab and it worked. I can select the polygon, edit the nodes as normal vector file, and add labels as you can see below:

Editing the files:

[image]

Labeling:

[image]

But when I save again the Tab file as shapefile it behaves as before (neither selection nor editing worked).

Solution is shown in the discussion below:**"...save the shapefile as MapInfo Format from QGIS by right-click the layer -> Save as and choose MapInfo Tab Format. Then continue working with file in QGIS."**

Comment: Thanks. I also found that these polygons are fine in ArcGIS. But once they are exported from ArcGIS and opened in QGIS, they became ghost shapes, again.

Comment: @oat I am not sure if MapInfo Tab is an option for you, but exporting the files as MapInfo Tab from QGIS can solve the problem

Comment: Unfortunately, we don't have MapInfo in our lab...

Comment: You don't need MapInfo, you can save the shapefile as MapInfo Format from QGIS by `right-click the layer -> Save as` and choose `MapInfo Tab` Format. Then continue working with file in QGIS

Comment: your suggestion solved my problem. You saved my day. Thank you.